# adding protoc to xcode

Tags: xcode, protocol-buffers

How does one add the protoc (Protocol Buffers) compiler to xcode so .proto files are compiled when building the project? also, these files have to be built first so the auto generated files are then available to the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Get Info on your target in Xcode and add a new build rule using the “+” button at the bottom of the Rules tab.